# Error "non-constant argument supplied to TIMES" from istruc use of a structure

Tags: assembly, struct, x86, nasm

I have recently started back up on my project and am getting an error when I compile my nasm program. I am using nasm 2.15.05 and am compiling in DOSBox, I have also tried FreeDOS in VirtualBox but I suspect it has nothing to do with the environment. The error that is produced is:

> `non-constant argument supplied to TIMES.`

I am not using `times` in the source file which threw me but I looked at the listing and it's the `istruc` macro.  Here is the relevant block from the listing file:

```
     0                              <1> times %$strucname_size-($-%$strucstart) db 0
     0 00000066 <len 1>             <1>  ;;; times COORD_size-($-..@39.strucstart) db 0
     0          ******************  <1>  error: non-constant argument supplied to TIMES
```

And here is the source of the structure:

```
    struc COORD
    .TopLeft:                   resw    2
    .BottomRight:               resw    2
    endstruc
```

And here is the implementation of the structure:

```
section data
.draw_data:
    istruc  COORD
        at COORD.TopLeft,           dw  10, 20
        at COORD.BottomRight,       dw  50, 150
    iend
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I did see another post about the same error but that was caused by a case-sensitivity issue which I do not see in this case.

Comment: Make sure that your `struc` definition is **before** the usage by `istruc`. If I copy your example into a test file in the correct order (`struc` first) it assembles without error. In the wrong order I can reproduce your error.

Comment: @ecm: Unless there's an existing duplicate Q&A, might as well post that as an answer.  In a lot of things, order doesn't matter, so it can be surprising when it does.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Please also provide the source code in question or a [mcve].

Comment: side-note: `section data` is non-standard.  Normally we use `section .data`.  If you're only making a `.com` flat binary then section names don't matter at all, but it's still a good habit to use standard names so defaults like read-write (.data) vs. read+exec (.text) will apply for object-file formats that support them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by defining the `struc` structure after its use by the `istruc` macro.

First, look at this test to see how it works correctly when using your example, with the `struc` occurring in the source before its use by `istruc`:

```
$ nasm -v
NASM version 2.15.03 compiled on Dec 28 2020
$ cat testpass.asm

struc COORD
 .TopLeft:      resw 2
 .BottomRight:  resw 2
endstruc

section data
.draw_data:
istruc COORD
 at COORD.TopLeft,      dw 10, 20
 at COORD.BottomRight,  dw 50, 150
iend

$ nasm testpass.asm
$
```

Next, we can reproduce your error if we swap the two blocks of code:

```
$ cat testfail.asm

section data
.draw_data:
istruc COORD
 at COORD.TopLeft,      dw 10, 20
 at COORD.BottomRight,  dw 50, 150
iend

struc COORD
 .TopLeft:      resw 2
 .BottomRight:  resw 2
endstruc

$ nasm testfail.asm
testfail.asm:7: error: non-constant argument supplied to TIMES
$
```

Further, let's look at the listing file. Recent NASM provides the `-Lp` switch to keep the listing file even in the case of errors. Use this and this is the result:

```
$ nasm testfail.asm -l testfail.lst -Lp
testfail.asm:7: error: non-constant argument supplied to TIMES
$ cat testfail.lst
     1
     2                                  section data
     3                                  .draw_data:
     4                                  istruc COORD
     5 00000000 <len 4h>                 at COORD.TopLeft,      dw 10, 20
     6 00000004 <len 4h>                 at COORD.BottomRight,  dw 50, 150
     6          ******************       error: TIMES value -4 is negative
     7 00000008 <len 1h>                iend
     7          ******************       error: non-constant argument supplied to TIMES
     8
     9                                  struc COORD
    10 00000000 <len 4h>                 .TopLeft:      resw 2
    11 00000004 <len 4h>                 .BottomRight:  resw 2
    12                                  endstruc
    13
$
```

We can see there's actually two errors. The "non-constant" error appears to take precedence over the "is negative" error however. Let's see what the `istruc` macros expand to:

```
$ nasm testfail.asm -E > efail.asm
$ nasm efail.asm -l efail.lst -Lp
testfail.asm:8: error: non-constant argument supplied to TIMES
$ cat efail.lst
     1                                  %line 2+1 testfail.asm
     3                                  [section data]
     4                                  .draw_data:
     5                                  ..@2.strucstart:
     6                                  times (COORD.TopLeft-COORD)-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0
     7                                  %line 5+0 testfail.asm
     5 00000000 <len 4h>                dw 10, 20
     5                                  %line 6+1 testfail.asm
     7                                  times (COORD.BottomRight-COORD)-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0
     7          ******************       error: TIMES value -4 is negative
     8                                  %line 6+0 testfail.asm
     6 00000004 <len 4h>                dw 50, 150
     6                                  %line 7+1 testfail.asm
     8 00000008 <len 1h>                times COORD_size-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0
     8          ******************       error: non-constant argument supplied to TIMES
     9
    10                                  [absolute 0]
    11                                  %line 9+0 testfail.asm
     9                                  COORD:
     9                                  %line 10+1 testfail.asm
    11 00000000 <len 4h>                 .TopLeft: resw 2
    12 00000004 <len 4h>                 .BottomRight: resw 2
    13                                  COORD_size equ ($-COORD)
    14                                  %line 12+0 testfail.asm
    12                                  [section data]
    12                                  %line 13+1 testfail.asm
    14
$
```

The `times` repetition causing the error is emited from `iend`, and is intended to pad the instance of the structure up to the full size of the structure. NASM structure labels, like labels in NASM generally, have no concept of a "label size", so after the last structure field's start label there could be an arbitrary amount of space reserved. To honour this space, whatever its size, NASM records the size of the structure in a label named like the structure with `_size` appended. The `times` directive evidently wants the `COORD_size` label to be defined before its use.

[In the manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.5) it says that "[t]he operand to TIMES is a critical expression", and links to [the section on critical expressions](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.8):

> defined to be an expression whose value is required to be computable in the first pass, and which must therefore depend only on symbols defined before it. The argument to the TIMES prefix is a critical expression.

So, using `COORD_size` before it is defined makes the critical expression not be computable.

### Digging deeper

Just for fun, let's look at what happens when we comment out the offending directive:

```
$ cat e2.asm
[section data]
.draw_data:
..@2.strucstart:
times (COORD.TopLeft-COORD)-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0
dw 10, 20
times (COORD.BottomRight-COORD)-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0
dw 50, 150
; times COORD_size-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0

[absolute 0]
COORD:
 .TopLeft: resw 2
 .BottomRight: resw 2
COORD_size equ ($-COORD)
[section data]
$ nasm e2.asm
$
```

It passes! Why is that? It appears that the deltas of the form `COORD.TopLeft - COORD` are actually allowed in the critical expression for `times`. I assume this is an artefact of NASM actually being a multi-pass assembler. It (correctly) guesses that the delta will evaluate to a scalar number. On an earlier pass, this is evaluated as zero, resulting in the "TIMES value -4 is negative" error. However, on a subsequent pass NASM *knows* the label values and inserts them so no error remains. I'm honestly not sure why this doesn't happen to the `COORD_size` use, but I assume it is related to NASM not knowing it will be equated to a scalar number later.

Just to make sure, here's the same test with the offending directive not commented out; it fails as before:

```
$ cat e3.asm
[section data]
.draw_data:
..@2.strucstart:
times (COORD.TopLeft-COORD)-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0
dw 10, 20
times (COORD.BottomRight-COORD)-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0
dw 50, 150
times COORD_size-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0

[absolute 0]
COORD:
 .TopLeft: resw 2
 .BottomRight: resw 2
COORD_size equ ($-COORD)
[section data]
$ nasm e3.asm
e3.asm:8: error: non-constant argument supplied to TIMES
$
```

Finally, modifying the example so as to use a delta for the size, helped by an additional label at the end of the structure, makes all `times` directives work as intended:

```
$ cat e4.asm
[section data]
.draw_data:
..@2.strucstart:
times (COORD.TopLeft-COORD)-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0
dw 10, 20
times (COORD.BottomRight-COORD)-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0
dw 50, 150
times (COORD_end-COORD)-($-..@2.strucstart) db 0

[absolute 0]
COORD:
 .TopLeft: resw 2
 .BottomRight: resw 2
COORD_end:
COORD_size equ ($-COORD)
[section data]
$ nasm e4.asm
$
```

Comment: Note for further research: It may be relevant that the failure occurs when an equate (`equ`) is used but does not occur when two plain labels (no `equ`) are used.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, only took me reading a few sentences to remember that I needed to include the definition into my program, how silly do I feel :) Second pair of eyes always helps.